# Validate radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, radio-button

```
function validate()
{
   var payment = checkRadio();
   if (payment == false)
   {
      alert("Please select one button")
   }
}

function checkRadio()
{
var payment = document.getElementsByName("payment");
for(i = 0; i < payment.length; i++)
    {
        if(payment[i].checked)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

The html code below creates the radio buttons for the client to select one of the payment methods

```
<P> Payment Options:
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="CC">Credit Card
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="DC">Debit Card
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="PP">PayPal 
</P>

<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">
```

My problem is that when I execute this code and run it on chrome nothing happens. If someone could spot out where about I went wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: where you calling `validate()` function?

Comment: `<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">` The function call is fine because I have other fields which I check whether it has been filled and they work fine, its just checking the radio buttons that is causing a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your html code with `<form>`

```
<form>
Payment Options:
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="CC">Credit Card
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="DC">Debit Card
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" Value="PP">PayPal 


<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="  SUBMIT  " onClick="validate()">  
</form>
```

And in your javascript change the checkRadio to:

```
function checkRadio()
{
var payment = document.getElementsByName('payment');

var paymentType = '';

for(i = 0; i < payment.length; i++)
    {    
        if(payment[i].checked)
        {
            console.log(payment[i].value)
            paymentType = payment[i].value;            
        }
   }
   return paymentType != '' ? true : false;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ttgrk8xj/16/

Comment: the windows.validate is just to automatically run the code without clicking anything, but in my code the validate function is only performed once you've clicked submit, it should then alert and say please select a button but nothing happens

Comment: I've  just eddited the answer and teste it. Take a look at the JSFiddle, please.

Comment: Thank you very much it works now, it was the `console.log(payment[i].value)` part

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are checking only the first element is checked because you are returning from function in first iteration.

```
function checkRadio()
{
  var payment = document.getElementsByName("payment");
  for(i = 0; i < payment.length; i++)
    {
        if(payment[i].checked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

  return false;
}
```